# FileNotFoundException(permission) when trying to write string from web to file

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, filenotfoundexception

i am trying to build an application that downloads files (e.g. ".jpg", ".txt") from the web when given a url. its not really meant to be a real world application, more just an exercise to help me become more comfortable with network and io based code. for now i am just pulling the bytes from the url and then converting them to a string and logging that. then from there i want to write this to a file. the problem i am running into now is that im getting a file not found exception stating that access is denied:

```
07-11 21:03:14.458 19072-20051/com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader E/AsyncDownload: network errorjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/-1157023572 (Permission denied)
                                                                                      java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/-1157023572 (Permission denied)
                                                                                          at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
                                                                                          at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
                                                                                          at com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader.AsyncDownload.doInBackground(AsyncDownload.java:60)
                                                                                          at com.example.zacharymcdaniel.webdownloader.AsyncDownload.doInBackground(AsyncDownload.java:23)
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                          at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and the code for the asynctask implementation i am using to perform the download and write operation:

```
public class AsyncDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
private static final String TAG = "AsyncDownload";
private static final String STORAGE_LOCATION = "/sdcard/"; //android directory picker is needed

private URL url;
private ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();

public AsyncDownload(URL url){
    this.url = url;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){

    try{
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) != -1){
            buffer.write(c);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, buffer.toString());

        Random rand = new Random(4L);
        String temp = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt());

        String finalLocation = STORAGE_LOCATION + temp;

        File file = new File(finalLocation);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.setWritable(true);
        file.setReadable(true);

        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fOut.write(buffer.toByteArray());
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(finalLocation);

        String reRead = new String();
        int a;
        while ((a = fIn.read()) != -1){
            reRead += a;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, reRead);

        //this section is for automatic file naming
        /*Random rand = new Random(5L);
        String fileNumber = String.valueOf(rand.nextInt());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(fileNumber).append("download"); //definitely needs work

        Log.i(TAG, sb.toString());*/

        //FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream()

    }catch (IOException ioe){
        Log.e(TAG, "network error" + ioe.toString(), ioe);
    }


    return null;
}
}
```

i am pretty new to this so i may have made some pretty obvious mistakes. please help solve this error. thank you.

Comment: What api level are you running on? From 6.0 or above, you have to ask user run time to gain permission if you write to external storage. You won't  need it if you write to your app specific storage.

Comment: If you are testing on the device which is above or android 6 you need to ask for read and write permissions

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your activity

```
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(InterviewListActivity.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_EXT_STORAGE);
    }
```

Comment: This is just half ot the things necessary.

Answer (score 1):

call this method in your activity

```
protected void checkPermissions() {
            final int writeExternalPermissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);



    if (writeExternalPermissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    Constant.REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    } 
}
```

and override this method

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constant.REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults!=null) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    //Call ur save method here or change the variable value true
                } else {
                   Logger.toast(this, "Please enable write permission from Apps); 

                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Hope This helps.

Answer (score 0):

Api level 6.0 or above you need runtime permission